# How to use enumerate package such that it enumerates letters not in sequential order?

Tags: enumerate

Essentially, when I render this

```
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item "Man cannot live by bread alone."
\item "To every thing there is a season, and a time for every purpose under heaven."
\end{enumerate}
```

I get

(a) "Man cannot live by bread alone."

(b) "To every thing there is a season, and a time for every purpose under heaven."

but I want

(b) "Man cannot live by bread alone."

(d) "To every thing there is a season, and a time for every purpose under heaven."

Edit: Basically, the code I have now enumerates the letters in the alphabet in order: (a), (b), (c), ... However, I want to *individually* choose the letters. How can I do this? Bringing it back to my original problem, I don't want (a),(b) but instead want (b), (d)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  If you're satisfied with manually numbering your items, you may want to give `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item[(b)] "Man cannot live by bread alone."
\item[(d)] "To every thing there is a season, and a time for every purpose under heaven."
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}` a try.

Comment: @leandriis Perfect! Thank you!